# Javascript: How to not directly post a variable

Tags: javascript

I am in need of help again, this time with a little Javascript snippet. There's also a little bit of PHP involved. The PHP is as follows (to generate random numbers)

```
$no1 = rand(0,9);
$no2 = rand(0,9);
$no3 = $no1+$no2;
```

I'm using this as a captcha method, for a very simple contact form. I'm not a fan of the bulky methods that I find all over google searches.

To validate this code, I use the following Javascript

```
if(document.forms["feedback"].check.value !== "<?php echo $no3; ?>"){
    window.alert("Incorrect security code");
    return false;
}
```

Then inside my form, I just use this:

```
<?php echo $no1; ?> + <?php echo $no2; ?> = <input name="check" type="text" id="check" size="3">
```

It all works as it's supposed to, but if there was a way for me to not to just directly echo $no3 in my javascript here:

```
if(document.forms["feedback"].check.value !== "<?php echo $no3; ?>")
```

Then that would eliminate any way of viewing the source to find the answer. I'm very much aware that it's a simple math problem, and if anyone knows how to view source, they most definitely can add, but a colleague of mine pretty much insisted on this.

So, does anyone know a way to help me out? I pretty much wrote most of this by hand, including the javascript, so please be nice when telling me that my code is horrible and out dated..

Thanks!

Comment: In order to keep the value out of the client-side code, you'd need to perform the check server-side.  So the user would have to post the form and you'd make the check there.  Or perhaps you can make an AJAX request to a server-side resource.  Either way, you'd need to store the value server-side in some way because the check would be on a completely different request than the one which generated it.  (Maybe store it in `$_SESSION`?)

Comment: Checking this on the client-side would be *super* easy for a script to bypass (just post directly rather than go through the form). You're really only creating an inconvenience for humans, and an easily skipped obstacle for bots.

Comment: Yeah, I knew this wasn't anywhere near the most secure way of doing things. However, I don't want to add one of the bulky other captcha scripts, they just look to be too much, I would ultimately like to keep everything within one file preferably. If any of you know of a better way, I'm completely open to a new method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `$no1` and `$no2` variables inside of `span` tags (or anything else you can directly target with Javascript) and then get the values from those spans with JS and use that to calculate the sum in JS rather than echoing it into the source with PHP, e.g. give the spans IDs like `#captcha-1` and `#captcha-2` use `getElementByID` to retrieve the values, then do the validation entirely in Javascript.

It will still be easy for anyone with a brain to figure out how to bypass but at least the answer will not be present anywhere in the source code other than as a JS variable.

If you want to hide the validation process entirely, you will need to use JS and AJAX to send the sum input by the user to a serverside PHP function which checks to see if it is equal to `$no1 + $no2` and then submit the form as part of the response success function.

All that being said, this is still a very weak spam deterrent method.

Comment: Yes, I'm very much aware it's weak, I had previously used a standard captcha script, that generated a random set of 5 alphanumeric characters within an image, but my client complained about it. So, I made this for him in a couple of minutes, and told him it's less secure but anyone could use it. If you know of another captcha script, where I could keep everything within one file, I'd be completely open to trying it.